# Cannot find "next page" button element of page and click it nor any info with Selenium in Python after accepting cookies

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies, webdriverwait

I'm learning how to scrape data from websites. I started with this page: https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/premier-league/torschuetzenliste/wettbewerb/GB1/saison_id/2020

I would like to extract the players name and goals they scored from this page and do it for the first few pages. Here is what I have

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

as preamble and then

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\bin\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/premier-league/torschuetzenliste/wettbewerb/GB1/saison_id/2020")

pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
Players = pageSoup.find_all("a", {"class": "spielprofil_tooltip"})
```

This correctly extracts the information I want of the first page. Now to click and go to second page, I do

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.naechste-seite').click()
```

(I must say I'm not sure this is the right way to do so... but from the information I have gathered on here and other sites, it seems that it should do the trick.) I receive an error,

> ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted:
> Element ... is
> not clickable at point (623, 695). Other element would receive the
> click:

This error comes from the fact that there is this cookie pop-up thing (at least here in Europe), that requires you to accept them or change them if you don't to continue browsing on the website). In order to accept all and just continue on the website, I did

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\bin\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/premier-league/torschuetzenliste/wettbewerb/GB1/saison_id/2020")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'//iframe[@id="sp_message_iframe_382444"]')))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(@title,'ACCEPT ALL')]"))).click()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

This seems to work as intended as my browser correctly clicks on the Cookie button 'accept all' and I end up on the right page. Something weird happens however. I can no longer access the data table. Indeed if I do like before:

```
pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
Players = pageSoup.find_all("a", {"class": "spielprofil_tooltip"})
```

Players is empty. And if I do

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.naechste-seite').click()
```

to go to next page, it gives me the error

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate
> element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"li.naechste-seite"}

I'm not sure what I should do.

Here is the html part of interest for the next page click "button" (I don't know if it can be of interested to any of you)

[image: html code part of interest]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable()` and following css selector.

Before that you need jump out from iframe.

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Then use

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"li.naechste-seite>a"))).click()
```

---

Your entire code would be

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\bin\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/premier-league/torschuetzenliste/wettbewerb/GB1/saison_id/2020")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'//iframe[@id="sp_message_iframe_382444"]')))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(@title,'ACCEPT ALL')]"))).click()
#Jump out from iframe
driver.switch_to.default_content()
#click on next button
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"li.naechste-seite>a"))).click()
```

Comment: Ok, this works. But could you explain me briefly why to do that so that I can reproduce it if need be later for other projects?
- Why exactly do I need to `switch_to.default_content` after a `click`. Why do I not need to do it for other types of clicks? 
- Why did you change the `element_to_be_clickable` to a search by `CSS_SELECTOR`? Is it better? Faster? More robust?
- Why this structure `"li.naechste-seite>a"` inside the search? (Why `"li.naechste-seite"` in the first place btw?)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @mwoua : 1) if you switch to `iframe` to access any element inside `iframe` then you need to jump out from `iframe` to access the element outside of the `iframe` in your case to access `next button` . 2)   Yes `CSS_SELECTOR` is much faster while executing code. 3) `li.naechste-seite>a` this css selector syntax `tagname.classname > intermediate child tag name` 4) `li.naechste-seite` this will work as well however I would prefer to click on clickable element and here it is `anchor` tag would be best option. Hope I have answered your query.Thanks